# Determining the convergence of $ \sqrt{n} \sin(\pi/\sqrt{n}) $

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find what this function converges to.

$$ \sqrt{n} \sin(π/\sqrt{n}) $$

I've taken the limit:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{n}\sin(π/\sqrt{n}) $$

It appears as though the function takes the following form as n approaches infinity:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \infty \sin(π/\infty) &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \infty\cdot \sin(0)\\
&= \infty
\end{align*}

I have been told that this converges to $\pi$, which means I'm doing something wrong here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Near $0$, $\sin x \approx x$.

Comment: One problem with what you are doing is that $0\cdot\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: Sine of zero is zero?

Comment: @Bob: Absolutely!

Comment: @Clayton Ah, so -near- zero sinx is approximately equal to x. That is an interesting behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your limit seems to be $\infty \times 0$, then you can't just conclude it's $\infty$ or $0$ or some definite value. The result depends on how strongly each factor approaches its limit.

As others suggest, the main thing is to substitute $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. I'd just like to add how to proceed if you don't know that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{x}=a$.

Limits like this are easily solved by the [L'Hôpital's_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Let's rewrite
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin(\pi/\sqrt{n})
= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} 
$$
Since both the numerator and denominator approach $0$ as $x\to 0$ and we can apply the rule:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} 
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(\pi x)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pi \cos(\pi x)}{1}  \\
&= \pi\cos 0 \\
&= \pi.
\end{align}
Since the limit on the RHS exists, we can conclude that the original limit is also $\pi$.

---

It'd be also possible to compute the limit using the rule directly, without any "smart" substitution. If we express it as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin(\pi/\sqrt{n}) =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi n^{-1/2})}{n^{-1/2}}
$$
we see that the numerator and denominator both approach $0$. Using the rule we compute
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\sin(\pi n^{-1/2})}{\frac{\partial}{\partial n}n^{-1/2}}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\pi n^{-3/2}\cos(\pi n^{-1/2})}{-\frac{1}{2}n^{-3/2}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\pi\cos(\pi n^{-1/2}) \\
&= \pi 
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Recall that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{x} = a$$

Comment: This problem is not in this form. It is being multiplied by $\sqrt{n}$ and not being divided by it.

Comment: Or is it in this form? Can this be rewritten?

Comment: @Bob: Yes, replace $x$ with the proper function of $n$ and the problem will be exactly in this form.

Comment: @Bob Set $x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$ and note that as $n \to \infty$, we have $x \to 0$.

Comment: How is such an identity true? You'd think that since the maximum value of the sine function on the numerator is a maximum of 1, and since the denominator is infinity, the fraction would take the form 1 / $\infty$ = 0.

My thinking seems to be flawed somewhere.

Comment: @Bob Why don't you first write it out on a piece of paper before leaving comments? It will help you a lot.

Comment: @user17762 I believe you may have misunderstood my last comment.

Comment: @Bob If you set $x = \dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$, we get $$\sqrt{n} \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \dfrac{\sin\left( \pi x\right)}{x}$$ Note that both the denominator and numerator tend to zero as $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: Right, but the numerator will equal 1 and the denominator will equal $\infty$ as x approaches $\infty$. 1 / $\infty$ = 0. This is where I am confused.

Comment: @Bob $\color{red}{x \to 0}$, since $n \to \infty$. So both numerator and denominator will tend to zero.

Comment: @Bob it is true because $\sin5x\approx5x$ for $x$ in the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Bob see the following Wolfram Alpha plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsin%285x%29%2C+y%3D5x%2C+y%3Dx

Comment: @user17762 That makes sense. Then I'd use L'Hospitals rule from that and eventually end up with pi as my answer?

Comment: @oldrinb That helped a lot.

Comment: @Bob so, then, despite $\sin5x$ having a maximum value of $1$, the ratio $\sin5x/x$ grows larger. Similarly, if we let $x=1/\sqrt{n}$, and replace $5$ with $\pi$, we similarly get $\sqrt{n}\sin(\pi/\sqrt{n})\to\pi$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
Let $t=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}$, use $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$$

Answer (score 1):

Try this question by writing the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$.

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
When you apply this expansion to the question, $\sqrt(n)$ gets cancelled from the numerator and the denominator thus leaving you with one term of the series independent of $n$. Now when you apply the limit, all the other terms tend to zero, as the term containing $n$ is in the denominator. As $n\to\infty$, all the terms tend to zero and the limit converges at $\pi$.

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted answer, I don't know how to use Math formatting on this website. Some help would be appreciated.